# Adding autoprefix-cli to ANT build

Tags: java, css, build, ant, autoprefixer

I am trying to add [autoprefix-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer-cli) to my ANT build. Below is my code.

```
<target name="auto">
<apply executable="autoprefixer-cli.bat" verbose="true" force="true" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-d" /> <!-- Turn on verbose -->
    <arg value="prefix" />
    <arg value="*.css" />  
</apply>
</target>
```

When i do a ant build, it gives me an error saying resource not specified.

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\tempTest\AntTestProject\build.xml:25: no resources specified
```

Note: I can access autoprefix-cli from command line, its installed with -g flag and also it works when i directly use it from commandline.

Comment: I am also trying to add prefixes in ant build, could you please help me with the process. Where did you get this .bat file. Do I need to install autoprefix somehow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `apply` task basically loops the `exec` task on a batch of resources (files, directories, URLs, etc). If you only want to run one command, use `exec` instead.

However, you will likely also need to alter your command. From Ant's `exec` task documentation:

> Note that .bat files cannot in general by executed directly. One
>   normally needs to execute the command shell executable cmd using the
>   /c switch.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

So instead you should have:

```
<exec executable="cmd" verbose="true" force="true" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="/c" />
    <arg value="autoprefixer-cli.bat" />
    <arg value="-d" />
    <arg value="prefix" />
    <arg value="*.css" />  
</exec>
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, any idea of using Autoprefixer-rails with Jruby(I am using the jar from website)?

https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with Jruby or rails